# Old TOR version

Tags: tor

Does anyone know where I can get older versions of TorBrowser and TorButton?

(Incase anyone needs to know why... I have a javascript app that runs in Firefox. Firefox have removed a vital feature I was relying on (netscape.security object). So I have to continue to use an old version (FF16). However the latest TorButton does not work with this version of Firefox and the last version I that I previously downloaded is very old.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/ is the place to go for archived releases.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for.